# How can I ensure consistency in CRS and units between a spatial polygon dataframe and a list of observations with coordinates?

Tags: spatial, coordinate-systems, units-of-measurement

I have two files, one is a spatial polygon dataframe with a country boundary. The second is a list of observations and associated coordinates.

I need to ensure that these files are in the same CRS and units.

The spatial polygon is currently:
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation:
+proj=utm +zone=28 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

I would like to convert the units to km. How do I do this?

Secondly, how do I ensure that the units and CRS are the same for both files. The co-ords in the second file should also be in epsg 4326.

Can anybody help - I feel like this should be a simple fix but I'm really stumped by it.

I have converted the list of observations into spatial points:

Obs <- SpatialPoints(coords = cbind(x_coord,y_coord))

But this has no CRS assigned from the looks of things:
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA

How can I make these two files consistent in the CRS and units?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.